I want a special image size for mobile and another for large device
Hello i want to modify the size and the position of the image when it’s on small device the only thing is that when i do changes it’s also changing the large device too Even when i do « sm:-300 » it do anything
here is my code
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { motion } from "framer-motion"
import { MouseParallaxChild, MouseParallaxContainer } from "react-parallax-mouse";

const AuthLayout = () => {
  const IsAuthenthicated = false;
  return (
    <>
      {IsAuthenthicated ? (
        <Navigate to ="/" />
      ) : (
        <>
          <section className="flex flex-1 justify-center items-center flex-col py-10">
            <Outlet />
          </section>

          {/* Utilisation de l'image en tant que fond d'écran */}
          <div
            className="wall1 hover-blur sm:63 xl:block h-screen w-screen object-cover bg-no-repeat absolute top-0 left-0 z-0"
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url("/assets/images/wall1.png")`  }}
          />

          {/* Votre contenu ici */}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default AuthLayout



read up on responsive web design, media queries, and breakpoints. All of those exist for Tailwind as well.

nevermind chatgpt answered my question lmao
"In this code, I've added a second image with the xl:hidden class, which means it will be hidden on screens larger than extra-large (XL) size. Also, I adjusted the size classes so that the image appears smaller on mobile screens."

You can check out the Tailwind documentation to learn about different breakpoints i.e. sm, md, lg, and xl.
Check this out
You can also add your own breakpoint in tailwind.config.js file. For example, if you want an extra small device, you can do this:
tailwind.config.ts
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx}'],
    mode: 'jit',
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
            },
            
            screens: {
                xs: '450px',
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [],
};

You can toggle the background properties based on the device size then like this. For instance, in an xs device you want the background to be in the center but in a device larger than this, you want it to be at the left, so you can do something like this:
<div
                    className=" bg-center xs:bg-left"
                    style={{ backgroundImage: `url("/assets/images/wall1.png")` }}
                />

By default the background position is center but in devices greater than xs or 450px, the background position becomes left. You can follow the same kind of implementation for all the other CSS properties too.

Nothing change i just want a modify size of my image on mobile and on pc it doesnt change

Can you please share the code snippets?

Media queries (CSS3) enables you to specify what happens to content based on screen size...
Example:
@media screen and (max-width:799px){

 .Flower{width:50px; height:50px;}

}


@media screen and (max-width:1200px){

 .Flower{width:100px; height:70px;}

}


It is specifically a Tailwind question!

it change on mobile and pc i only want it change on mobile
